# scala.math.BigInt cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: scala, casting, sbt, long-integer

I'm getting above error when calling this function

```
def filterOutNoInvPrices(storeNum: Long, inventoryMap: Map[Long, Long]) = {
    val inv = inventoryMap.get(storeNum)
    val minimumUnitsCheck:Boolean = inv.nonEmpty && inv.get.toInt > 3
    println("what" + minimumUnitsCheck)
    if (minimumUnitsCheck) {
      Some(storeNum, inv.get)
    }
    else
      None
  }
```

To be more specific, it's on the line `inv.nonEmpty && inv.get.toInt > 3`.
The function where I called `filterOutNoInvPrices` is `getBasicStats`:

```
def getBasicStats(priceMap:Map[Long, String], invMap:Map[Long, Long])={
    priceMap
      .toSeq
      .map(storeAndPrice => {
        val price = getPriceAndPriceType(storeAndPrice._2)._1
        (price, filterOutNoInvPrices(storeAndPrice._1, invMap))})
      .filter(_._2.nonEmpty)
      .map(record => (record._1, record._2.get))
  }
```

Before I called this function, I explicitly let inventoryMap to be `Map[Long, Long]`.

```
val invMap:Map[Long, Long] = inventoryMap
val pMap:Map[Long, String] = priceMap
val basicStats = getBasicStats(pMap, invMap)
```

My code compiles successfully. I'm getting this error when running tests. I did pass my own test data, but if it's caused by the data, should the data mapping fail earlier?(for example happens when I explicitly claimed the map?) this is far bottom down.

1. I don't understand why I'm getting this error
2. where did I get the BigInt.
3. why it's casting to java.lang.Long rather than scala.Long.

The most recent stack trace is `scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)`

Comment: `inventoryMap` has a `BigInt` instead of `Long` ... Yeah, it should fail somewhere, if used correctly, but without seeing the code, hard to theorize where the problem is.

Comment: please post your error stacktrace so that its easier see whats going on. code does not seem to fail based on your definition

Comment: Hi @Dima, please see my update.

Comment: Where does `inventoryMap` come from? You need to show how it is initialized. FWIW `val invMap:Map[Long, Long] = inventoryMap` doesn't do anything to the contents of the map, it just creates an alias.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I thought it was explicit type reference like other language. My fault. I thought it would fail.